# VB.Net thread issue

Tags: vb.net, events

I am trying to use a DLL that has a public class called FileCleanUp

Inside this class is a procedure called ProcessFiles as shown

```
public void ProcessFiles(string fileName)
{
    this.ProcessFiles(fileName, new ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.ProgressChangedHandler), new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.WorkCompleteHandler));
}
```

In VB.Net how do I access the ProcessFiles events so I can inform the user on progress etc from my VB.net application that calls this DLL.

By using Reflector have found that the DLL uses the Background Worker if this is of help.

If this is possible to do - please could you show me a code example \ brief solution.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For your code snippet, ProcessFiles is  looks like all you need to do is add a reference to this DLL, create a new instance of `FileCleanUp` and call `ProcessFiles(string)`
you may have to pass in `ProgressChangedHandler` and 'WorkCompleteHandler' (class property or constructor) but it's evident from your snippet.

```
Dim fileCleanUp as New FileCleanUp()
...
...
fileCleanUp.ProcessFiles(someString)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - do you know how I can access the events?

Comment: @Ben it depends on if and how it's exposed by the `FileCleanUp` class. Can you maybe post more code from that class?